# QTableWidget: Insert row crashes the application python

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have created a table and I want the row should be created based on click on one button. I created a table and I didn't assign rowcount. When I run program, it shows table without any row (shows header label etc). So far everything is fine. I put a button to add a row and wrote following code:

```
self.tableWidget.InsertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount()+1)
```

The application simply exits.

If I try:

```
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(count+1)
```

it adds row. Suppose I entered some data in rows and again call

```
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(count+1)
```

it deletes data of one row.

My question is:

Can we use InsertRow without setting setRowCount?

When I call setRowCount multiple time, why does it delete data filled in rows (using UI)?

Comment: `setRowCount` is called with `count`.  Is that the same value each time?

Comment: It should be `insertRow` with a lowercase `i`

Comment: @DavidChing Thanks for comments. The count is getting incremented every with every call. When I run the program, it adds the row. Suppose 3 rows created and user entered data in the rows. Now user wants to add one more row and data. When the setRowCount gets called, one blank row gets added but the data of one existing row deleted :-( .

Comment: I tried with lowercase i but it doesn't add any row

Comment: You call setRowCount with this mysterious `count`. What is it set to?

Comment: After changing to lowercase did the crash stop?  If not what was the stack trace?  When Python crashes it can be configured to show you what line of code caused the crash and the reason.

Answer (score 2):

I could implement something simpler to show exactly just what you are asking for, but I just implemented something similar to what you need, I needed to do what you need to get data from a table and fill out my QLineChart.

In summary you have to override all the required methods a QAbstractItemModel requires according to your needs.

Have this small example that I add a line to the and of my table when clicking in a button:

```
import random

from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractItemModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor


class ItemModelLineChart(QAbstractItemModel):

    signal_update_models = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(ItemModelLineChart, self).__init__()
        self.m_column_count = 2
        self.m_row_count = 0
        self.m_mapping = {}
        self.m_data = []
        # self.fill_with_random_data()

    def fill_with_random_data(self):
        print(self.m_row_count)
        for r in range(self.m_row_count):
            data_vec = [None] * self.m_column_count
            for c in range(len(data_vec)):
                if (c%2)==0:
                    data_vec[c] = r*50+random.randint(0,100)%20
                else:
                    data_vec[c] = random.randint(0, 100) % 20
            self.m_data.append(data_vec)

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.m_data)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.m_column_count

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=None):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            if section%2==0:
                return "x"
            else:
                return "y"
        else:
            return "{}".format(section+1)

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.m_data[index.row()][index.column()]
        elif role == Qt.EditRole:
            return self.m_data[index.row()][index.column()]
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            for color, rect in self.m_mapping.items():
                if rect.contains(index.column(), index.row()):
                    return QColor(color)
        return QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=None):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.EditRole:
            self.m_data[index.row()][index.column()] = int(value)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)
            self.signal_update_models.emit()
            return True
        return False

    def get_data(self, index):
        return self.m_data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def add_mapping(self, color, area):
        self.color = color
        self.area = area
        self.m_mapping[color] = area

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        # if (index.column() == 0):
        #     return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        # else:
        #     return Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def index(self, row, column, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.hasIndex(row,column,parent):
            return self.createIndex(row,column,self.m_data[row])
        return QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index=None):
        return QModelIndex()

    def insertRows(self):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.m_row_count, self.m_row_count)

        self.m_data.append([0,0])
        self.m_row_count += 1
        self.add_mapping(self.color, QRect(0, 0, 2, self.rowCount()))
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

    def removeRows(self):
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), self.m_row_count, self.m_row_count)
        self.m_data.pop()
        self.m_row_count -= 1
        self.endRemoveRows()

        return True

    def add_row(self):
        self.insertRows()

    def remove_row(self):
        if self.m_row_count>0:
            self.m_row_count -= 1
            self.removeRows()
```

**and in the widget or whatever you have your buttons just connect your button clicking to the insert and remove line methods from your item model above.**

```
#...
    def create_connections(self):
        self.btn_add_line.clicked.connect(self.table.model().insertRows)
        self.btn_remove_line.clicked.connect(self.table.model().remove_row)
#...
```

**Now you just gotta set the model from your tableview to the model you overwrote.**

Comment: Thanks for quick and detailed reply. Looks like you used QTableView where we use datamodel. I am using QTableWidget, do I need to create model? I suppose model is needed for view only.

Comment: @Manish If you choose QTableWidget you don't need to have your own model. It's already much more robust and have many own functions you can use to do what you need, otherwise if you care about memory and you don't want to waste it I'd recommend you to use QTableView with your own personalized QAbstractItemModel. In summary, QTableWidget is a QTableView with many things already implemented under the hood. ")

Comment: The QTableView is so different than QTableWidget, I think a new example showing QTableWidget is needed.